# Pyinstaller ModuleNotFoundError on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to make my python program into an app using pyinstaller. This works flawlessly in Windows, but is not working on Mac OS (Big Sur). I've installed pyinstaller version 5.0dev0.

I started the virtual environment and ran pyinstaller in terminal with the following. (Ultimately, I want to run it as --onefile and without the debug stuff):

```
(klusterbox) thomasweeks@Thomass-MacBook-Pro kb_install % pyinstaller -w -D -i kb_sub/kb_images/kb_icon1.icns --log-level DEBUG > out.txt klusterbox.py
```

When I click on the app or open it in terminal, the icon appears in the dock for an instant and disappears. Nothing else happens. When I the Unix Executable File in the dist directory, the, terminal opens and give me this:

```
Last login: Fri Jan 15 22:24:13 on ttys002
thomasweeks@Thomass-MacBook-Pro ~ % /Users/thomasweeks/klusterbox/kb_install/dist/klusterbox/klusterbox ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "klusterbox.py", line 58, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
[24871] Failed to execute script klusterbox
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

This is line 58 in the python program:

```
# Pillow Library
from PIL import ImageTk, Image  # Pillow Library
```

The Pillow module is installed in the virtual environment:

```
(klusterbox) thomasweeks@Thomass-MacBook-Pro klusterbox % pip3 list
Package            Version
------------------ --------
...
openpyxl           3.0.3
pdfminer.six       20181108
Pillow             8.0.1
pip                20.3.1
...
```

My .spec file looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['klusterbox.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/thomasweeks/klusterbox/kb_install'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='klusterbox',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False , icon='kb_sub/kb_images/kb_icon1.icns')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='klusterbox')
app = BUNDLE(coll,
             name='klusterbox.app',
             icon='kb_sub/kb_images/kb_icon1.icns',
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

I've got more raw data if you need to see it.

Comment: Is the application a ```.exe```?

Comment: In finder the file is identified as "Application" the other file is identified as "Unix Executable File".

Comment: Try adding a hidden import to `pillow` in your spec file, like `hiddenimports=['pillow']`

Comment: I tried that. Thanks but it did not work. The only thing that works so far is to add the PIL folder to the same directory as the klusterbox.py file. But I can only run the program with the Unix Executable File. The app opens, then immediately closes.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I found out later that the below method was made irrelevant by running pyinstaller from inside the virtual environment. After I uninstalled pyinstaller using 'pip uninstall pyinstaller' outside of the virtual environment. I started the virtual environment then installed pyinstaller inside the virtual environment with 'pip install pyinstaller'. After this, pyinstaller found the needed modules. End of edit.

This is a partial answer, where I was able to solve part of the problem. First I went to terminal, navigated to the project folder and made sure the virtual environment was running:

```
pipenv shell
```

Next I looked for the missing module which is cited in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'.

```
pip show Pillow
```

This gives the following report:

```
(klusterbox) thomasweeks@Thomass-MacBook-Pro kb_install % pip show Pillow
Name: Pillow
Version: 8.0.1
Summary: Python Imaging Library (Fork)
Home-page: https://python-pillow.org
Author: Alex Clark (PIL Fork Author)
Author-email: aclark@python-pillow.org
License: HPND
Location: /Users/thomasweeks/.local/share/virtualenvs/klusterbox-K4ySO0c7/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

I copied the location from the terminal and opened up my klusterbox.spec file. You you it will be .spec in your project folder. I changed the value of pathex in the Analysis tuple in the .spec file.

```
...
a = Analysis(['klusterbox.py'],
             pathex=['/Users/thomasweeks/.local/share/virtualenvs/klusterbox-K4ySO0c7/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Users/thomasweeks/klusterbox/kb_install'],
             binaries=[],
...
```

So the pathex value of the Analysis tuple now contains two locations, the location of the project folder and the location of the site packages in the virtual environment. I didn't change anything else in the spec file.

I deleted the old dist, build and **pycache** folders in Finder.

In terminal I re-ran pyinstaller using the .spec file instead of the .py file. This runs pyinstaller so that it is configured by your revised spec file.

```
pyinstaller klusterbox.spec
```

Pyinstaller runs, creates the dist, build and **pycache** folders. Opening the dist folder there is a klusterbox file (Unix Executable File) and a klusterbox.app file. The klusterbox.app file still will not open, but the Unix Executable File does open and runs although there is a terminal window even though I specified no console in the spec file.